# How to implement a ngModel parser using Typescript

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I'm working on a directive which capture a date using the [UI Bootstrap Datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker), but I want to format the entered date prior to be passed to the bound model using the ngModel directive. This leads me to the implementation of a parser, looking at the interface definition it looks like this:

```
interface IModelParser {
  (value: any): any;
}
```

When I try to define a class called 'DateFilter' implementing it, the intellisense keeps showing me this:

> Type 'DateFilter' provides not match for the signature '(value: any): any'

So I would like to know how I should implement it, since there's no method or property name in that definition. I know this is such a basic question, but I've been looking for some example or documentation about it with no success yet. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found it in the Typescript documentation for [Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html). Turns out that's a Function type definition. So, my implementation now looks like this:

```
private dateFilter: ng.IModelParser = function (value: any): any {
        //Parse the value here
}
```

and now I'm able to push it into the ngModel parsers:

```
ngModel.$parsers.push(this.dateFilter);
```